# Assigning value by index in xarray assignes whole array

Tags: c++, xtensor

I use "xtensor" library for c++. With its help i try to create a datatable class that contain the user data.
Sometimes i need to subset some user group data by the users id list. For this task I use boolean flag system to mark users i want to copy to a new table.

```
class UserDataTable {
private:
   xt::xarray<bool> which;
//... more code
}

UserDataTable::UserDataTable(int size){

//... more code

   std::vector<std::size_t> shape(size, 1);
   std::vector<bool> boolinit(size);
   which = xt::adapt(binit, shape);

//... more code 
}
```

In subset function there is this code:

```
for(int usercounter=0; usercounter<USER_LIST_COUNT; usercounter++){
    std::string id = userlist(usercounter);
    if(indexMap.count(id)>0){
        int index = indexMap[id];
        which(index) = true;
    }
}
```

But this line of code:
which(index) = true; 
assigns "true" value to all "which" array elements.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is a special case. `operator[]` returns reference [`std::vector<bool>::reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference) and

> Any reads or writes to a vector that happen via a
>   `std::vector<bool>::reference` potentially read or write to the entire
>   underlying vector.

Comment: Great. Seems like changing xt::xarray<bool> to xt::xarray<int> may resolve my problem
Thank you.

Comment: @MadKoala Better than a "thank you", you can (should?) accept this answer by clicking the checkmark under its score.

Comment: @Killzone Note that this is not true as of C++17 per [`[vector.bool]/4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.bool#4). I don't know if cppreference is wrong or outdated. It might be a bug of xtensor; that wouldn't be the first bug `std::vector<bool>` introduces.